# why azure function app logs not coming properly?

Tags: azure-functions

Iam using azure function app and using a getting a api url response there.

```html
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var result = axios.get('********************');
    context.log('Workingggggggggg',result);
}
```

this is the part of code which is there.

But in logs this is the response I get.

2022-09-27 09:17:02.172
'Workingggggggggg Promise {  }'

What is this promise pending?

Answer (score 0):

- If you trying to print the response of the `axios.get()` then you have not configured it properly.

```
var  result = axios.get("url").then(
        resp  =>{
                    console.log(resp.data);
                    console.log("Response of the axios");// this is optional 
                    }
        );
```

this would log the like this if you call google url :

[image]